# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Ребят, решил помочь другу.
Теперь сам маюсь с этим и не знаю, в чем проблема.
Ему задали рипнуть сайт http://www.insymbiosis.com
Получился сайт http://talentport.org/
Он обратился ко мне с парой проблем, возникшими в связи с переездом, одна из которых - проблема с меню.
Меню навигации по страницам: Если кликнуть на ссылке "открыть в новой вкладке", страница прогружается, но если простой клик, происходит остановка дебаггером, прогружается бэк, и вылазит ошибка от jquery:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

И как я смотрю, за undefined он принимает document.
Я пытаюсь разобраться, в чем проблема, за любую помощь буду брагодарен

Comment: "не делай другу добра, ..."

Comment: Уже починили? В хроме сейчас не удается воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: @br3t
нет, проблема так и осталась: http://joxi.ru/L21G56Ytl4VBrX

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам необходимо подгружать аяксом весь `head` и повторные подключения уже подключенных скриптов? + для дебага полезно было бы подключать неминифицированные файлы по отдельности вместо bundle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрываю по причине того, что решили переделать сайт собственными силами. Всем спасибо за принятое участие.